# laravel working with city and area select

Tags: php, laravel, html-select

I was wondering if there is an easy way to work with multiple select boxes in Laravel. I am trying to make a city box, if the city is selected, if want to load the next controller that shows the areas in the city. Would this even be possible for a form?

Thank you

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: It would even be possible for a form. Google keywords: "populate form via ajax"

Comment: Does laravel have anything already built in as far as anybody knows? Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: This is not really a laravel question, this is a javascript question. You'll need to do this by either populating all possible options and then filtering with javascript, or by making an ajax request to populate each area based on selection. No there is nothing "built in" to laravel to handle this.

Comment: Indeed, after spending my morning with this, it seems that the only possibility would be jquery and ajax. I titled it laravel, because maybe laravel had an option included for this. I would guess a lot of people want to use something like this. At last, I made it myself this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys.

It was quite easy to make. 
Never expected it to be this easy.

I did it by setting a route to a new controller and working with javascript.

To the people that would like to make this in the near future.

Below you can find an idea of code that I have used for Laravel;

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#city').change(function () {
                var city = $("#city option:selected").val(); 
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://anma-maching-dev.aska-ltd.jp/destinations", 
                    data: { 
                        "city" : city
                    },
                    success: function(result){
                        jQuery('.area').html('');
                        $( ".area" ).fadeIn("fast", function() {
                            $(".area").append(result); 
                        });
                    } 
                });
            }); 
        });
```

I attached the output of the controller to a div class called area!

**route**

```
Route::get('/destinations', 'destinationsController@get_area');
```

**strong text**

```
public static function get_area()
{ 

    // your query to select the next information for your textBox

}
```